# Trying to update a product metadata via Woocommerce REST API in C#

Tags: c#, rest, woocommerce

```
public async Task<string> DoSomething()
{
    MyRestAPI rest = new MyRestAPI(url, key, secret);
    WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

    var tasks = await wc.Product.Update(id: ulong.Parse(txtPID.Text),
            new Product {
                name = txtName.Text,
                price = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text),
                meta_data = new ProductMeta { id:23323,value = "something"}
                } );
        
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tasks);
}
```

I was about to update different parts of the product like the name, description, and price but I am unable to find the away to update the metadata of the product itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that actually worked for me, I hope someone finds it
helpfull.

```
    public async Task<string> DoProductUpdate()
    {
        //connection parameters to the rest api woocommerce.net plugin
        MyRestAPI rest = new MyRestAPI(url, key, secret);
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

        //Product variable declaration
        Product p = new Product();

        // text field from which to get the new name of the product
        p.name = txtPName.Text;

        // text field from which to get the price of the product converted into integer.
        p.price = Int32.Parse(txtPPrice.Text);

        // meta id which is going to be updated converted from text to ulong integer
        var CostMetaid = ulong.Parse(txtPMetaID.Text);

        // meta id which is going to be updated converted from text to ulong integer
        var CostMeta2id = ulong.Parse(txtPMetaID2.Text);
        
        //Declaration of a productmeta list to hold the meta items which are going to be attached to the product created above
        var pm = new List<ProductMeta>()
        {
            new ProductMeta{id = CostMetaid, key = "_alg_wc_cog_cost", value = Int32.Parse(txtPCost.Text) },
            new ProductMeta{id = CostMeta2id ,key= "_wc_cog_cost",value=Int32.Parse(txtPCost2.Text)}
        };

        // attach list of meta items to the product variable
        p.meta_data = pm;

        //call the await product update function using the product id and the product object which contains all the product details to be updated
        var tasks = await wc.Product.Update(id: ulong.Parse(txtPID.Text), p); 

        return null;
    }
```